# Creating Correlation Matrix Tables with multiple variables within one measurement

Tags: correlation, spss, measurement, variable

trying my luck here since no one in my surroundings has worked with SPSS before
and I am also clearly a newbie to SPSS and statistics.

For my master degree I am researching possible correlations/a possible relationship between variables of Social Media Use and Purchase Intention Behavior.
While variables such as gender or education or usually single chart data within one variable/measurement, I used different scales to measure levels of Social Media Use and Purchase Intention Behavior.

Within the survey I had several items to measure levels of Social Media Use (e.g. time used, reason for use,..) and therefore I have several data sets for each of those measures. While I am able to run bivariate correlation analyses to check for possible correlations among those sets, I was wondering how I should "summarize" them in order to put them all under the variable of e.g. "Social Media Use" to further check for correlations between that variable and others with multiple data sets.

I hope what I explained made sense as I am quite new to this and am not really sure with those things.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why wouldn't factor analysis work?